# view encrypted variable in playbook gives "unbalanced" error

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that runs correctly when used with ansible-playbook.
It contains an encrypted variable. According to the manual https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#id16, I can view the variable with

> $ ansible localhost -m ansible.builtin.debug -a var="ansible_value" -e
> "'debug_playbook.yml" --vault-password-file=./pw_file

But I get an error of

ERROR! failed at splitting arguments, either an unbalanced jinja2 block or quotes: 'debug_playbook.yml

As the playbook itself runs, presumably its syntax is correct.

The playbook is

```yaml
- name: Run a series of debug tasks to see the value of variables
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_password: vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          63343064633966653833383264346638303466663265363566643062623436383364376639636630
          3032653839323831316361613138333999999999999999999a313439383536353737616334326636
          63616162323230333635663364643935383330623637633239626632626539656434333434316631
          3965373931643338370a393530323165393762656264306130386561376362353863303232346462
          3039
  user: myuser
  tasks:
    - name: show env variable HOME and LOGNAME
      debug:
        msg: "environment variable {{ item }}"
      with_items:
      - "{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}"
      - "{{ lookup('env','LOGNAME') }}"
    - name: now show all of the variables for the current managed machine
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] }}"
    - name: now show all of the hosts in the group from inventory file
      debug:
        msg: "server {{ item }}"
      with_items:
      - "{{ groups.mintServers }}"
      - "{{ groups.centosServers }}"
```

I have googled the error and nothing jumps out (to me anyway). Is the manual correct? I have seen other methods where the encrypted variable is echoed into ansible-vault decrypt but it is all a bit of a bother.

I have yamllint'd the playbook. So interested to know what the error means and a way of debugging.

Regards

Comment: 1) The example in the documentation is to read value from a varialble file not a playbook. Loading a playbook as extra var is not possible as the corresponding top level object needs to be a dict, not a list 2) There is a typo in your command. The syntax to load a file as extra var is `-e @the_file.yml`

Comment: 3) your variable is missing a `!` in front of vault in the definition of the value => `!vault |`

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator, thanks for this.  Good point about the missing ! and @. 
I can get to display the encrypted variable from the playbook by adding a debug task and using ansible-playbook. (simply just to see it work).
But to use the method in the docs, then it has to be in a seperate env file, which is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comments: you cannot view an encrypted var inside a playbook with the technique proposed in the documentation, for memory:

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a "var=your_var" \
  -e @your_file.yml --ask-vault-password
```

This will only work if your file is a "simple" var file where the top level element is a dictionary.

What I have done in the past is use the `yq` command line tool (which is a wrapper above `jq`) that you can easily install with `pip install yq`. (Note that `jq` needs to be installed separately and is available in most linux distribution channels. On ubuntu: `apt install jq`).

Once the prerequisites are available you can use `yq` to extract the var from you playbook and decrypt it with `ansible-vault` directly.

For this to work, you will still need to fix your var value which is not a valid vault definition as it misses a question mark in front of the vault marker:

```yaml
  vars:
    ansible_password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          63343064633966653833383264346638303466663265363566643062623436383364376639636630
          3032653839323831316361613138333999999999999999999a313439383536353737616334326636
          63616162323230333635663364643935383330623637633239626632626539656434333434316631
          3965373931643338370a393530323165393762656264306130386561376362353863303232346462
          3039
```

The solution is not so trivial as `yq` will get the vault value adding some garbage white-space and new line at the end that will make `ansible-vault` literally freak out. With your above fixed playbook example, this would give:

```
yq -r '.[0].vars.ansible_password|rtrimstr(" \n")' your_playbook.yaml \
  | ansible-vault decrypt --ask-vault-pass
```

Comment: I used something similar when I mentioned about the bother of echo'ing the value, piping it into tr and piping that into ansible-vault decrypt.
But I am taking the overall message as better to have encrypted variables in their own vars file.